# How do I get WakeOnLAN working when my network controller uses the sky2 module?

Tags: kernel, wakeonlan

I have an Aopen i945GMM-HL motherboard.  It still works fine, and the BIOS is set to allow WakeOnLAN to power up the machine but since a recent OS update those magic packets just don't work anymore.

Here's the output of lspci -v for the NIC:

```
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8053 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 22)
    Subsystem: AOPEN Inc. Device 0607
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 43
    Memory at fdefc000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    I/O ports at ce00 [size=256]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at fdd00000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [48] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [50] Vital Product Data
    Capabilities: [5c] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/2 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [e0] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Kernel driver in use: sky2
```

running ver. 3.4.6-1 of the kernel.

Answer (score 1):

The below information is from the OP, as he can't answer his own question for 7 more hours.

The solution for this problem was quite simple.  Apparently back when the kernel I used to use was made, power management options were never read from the BIOS.  All that changed, but some BIOSes report their data incorrectly resulting in breakage of some power management features for some users.  Workarounds were posted to the Linux Kernel Mailing List as patches but it was decided to add a module option instead.

So. If you're having a hard time getting wakeonlan to work with your system despite what ethtool & your BIOS settings say, try putting this into a .conf file (e.g. sky2.conf) in /etc/modprobe.d/

```
options sky2 legacy_pme=1
```

FYI, if unloading the sky2 module to try it with the legacy_pme option yourself, be sure to set wakeonlan back on with

```
sudo ethtool -s eth0 wol g
```

before powering the system down

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to share some information - this may help with your wakeonlan (WOL) issue with the Marvell device.

I have a Shuttle device with Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8056 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 12). I have been running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS and XBMC, with the Sky2 driver v1.25. WOL running just fine in this setup.

I recently had to upgrade to 12.04 LTS as part of  another story, and run into the WOL problem not working anymore with Sky2 v1.30

The Sky2 driver fails because of parameter handling of `Y2_HW_WOL_ON` and `Y2_HW_WOL_OFF` and the register writes, during the `sky2_wol_init` function.

I am by no means a Linux developer, but using a combination of `lspci` and `setpci` commands, I sniffed out the registers in the Marvell device that were set by the driver v1.25 and the driver v1.30, and now set the register manually with setpci when running the v1.30 driver. Wakeonlan works again with 12.04 LTS and v1.30 driver without any recompiling!

The register (in my system) is at `0x41`, and needs its value setting to `0x80`. My Marvell chip is on the PCI bus at `02:00.0`, found using `lspci`.

I added this command in the same startup script used to run the ethtool sequence:

```
setpci -s 02:00 41.b=80
```

So, a nasty hack, but works fine. I would fix the `sky2.c` driver if I knew how to build a kernel driver on my system…